# React Color Picker on bootstrap navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-rails

I added a **ColorpickerBackground** component to change the body background color of my app. This is working well...

My problem is when I add a new component **ColorpickerNavbar** to change the color of my bootstrap (4) navbar it doesn't work as expected. 
The color is changed after save, but the goal is to see the live change...

The `!important` is needed, but I dont know how to set it, and IF I have to set it in the react component....

This is the html of my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top" style= "background: <%= prefered_navbar_color %>!important;" id="my_nav">
 ...
</nav>
```

This is the html where the colorpicker appears:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :navbar_color %>
                            <%= react_component('ColorpickerNavbar', { navbar_color: prefered_navbar_color, selector: 'customization_navbar_color'} ) %>
                        </div>
```

ColorpickerNavbar.js

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color'


class ColorpickerNavbar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { selector: props.selector };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (navbar_color) => {
    let myNav = document.getElementById("my_nav")
    myNav.style.background = navbar_color.hex;

    let elem = document.querySelector('#' + this.state.selector);

    elem.value = navbar_color.hex;
  }


  render(){
    return  (
        <React.Fragment>
          <SketchPicker navbar_color={this.props.navbar_color}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ColorpickerNavbar.propTypes = {};

export default ColorpickerNavbar
```

Answer (score 2):

use the method setAttribute:

```
myNav.setAttribute('style', 'background: ' + navbar_color.hex + ' !important;')
```